# Please identify this curve fitting formula

Tags: math, formula, curve-fitting, equation, non-linear-regression

I have some non-linear data that I am trying to fit to an equation and have very little experience with this. I have found this formula, which best fits my data:

> y0 + a/(x-x0)

x being my data, y0, a, and x0 are the parameter estimates. I found this formula on https://plot.ly/create/ after creating a line chart with my x,y data and going to the Analysis > Curve Fitting option. It doesn't give a name for this equation.

Now I would like to begin to work backwards (ie calculate y0, a, and x0), but need to identify this equation to find more reading material for it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I believe it's called a rational function? With that aside, flagging to close due to off-topic.

Comment: Looks like a reciprocal function with an asymptote at x = x0.  It's singular at that point.  It has two branches - one to the right of the asymptote and another to the left that is its mirror image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [hyperbola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola) curve.

You can get such curve having the simplest `y=1/x` curve, then shifting it right by `x0` (vertical asymptote), stretching in vertical direction `a` times and shifting in vertical direction by `y0` (horizontal asymptote)

[example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%202%20%2B%203%20%2F%20(x-1),%20x%3D-1..4)